# VBA: Errors with IF loop to rename worksheets (specific errors)

Tags: excel, syntax-error, rename

I am trying to have the program search the workbook to CHECK if there is a "Sheet1" and/or "Sheet2". IF there is, I would like them to be renamed "Results" and "DataEntries" (see code below). IF the sheets are already named from previous runs) THEN continue the code with the new names. [the first time a user runs the program, the workbook may have sheet1 and sheet2 as default. My program stores the previous run, so if the user has run the program previously, sheet1 and sheet2 may already have the new and correct names)

The first lines of my code are as follows:

```
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If ws.Name = Sheet1 Then
            Sheet1.Name = Results
        ElseIf ws.Name = Sheet2 Then
            Sheet2.Name = DataEntries
        End If
    Exit For
    Next ws

Results.Cells.Clear
DataEntries.Cells.Clear
```

I receive the following errors in this exact order when trying to run the program:

1) object doesnt support this property or method

2) Method 'Name' of object '_Worksheet' failed

3) Object required

4) Object required

Then the program continues to run (although NOT performing the actions I would like). It must be simple syntax confusion but I cannot solve this issue. Can somebody point me in the right direction please? Will post remaining code if needed, but it might not be necessary.

Comment: is there `Option Explicit` at the top of your module? I assume there isn't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**, you should use `Option Explicit` which is a result of `Require Variable Declaration` option set to true in VBA editor options. If you did so I think some/all of your problems you could solve on your own.

**Second**, your `Results` and `DataEntries` are recognised as empty variables. If so you try to change sheets names into empty string which is not allowed. So you need to make the following changes (adding some quotation marks):

```
    If ws.Name = "Sheet1" Then
        Sheet1.Name = "Results"
    ElseIf ws.Name = "Sheet2" Then
        Sheet2.Name = "DataEntries"
    End If
```

**Third**, your loop will be run only once as you have `Exit For` line executed during first iteration- you should remove it as I can't find the reason to place it there.

**Fourth**, there could be some more problems but not seeing all the code it's difficult to recognise them all.

Comment: I have made all of these corrections and now receive error "Invalid qualifier" at the line "DataEntries.Cells.Clear" (added to original code)

Comment: @AlexBarrie, call it in this way: `Sheets("DataEntries").cells.clear` and code should work...

Comment: Perfect, THANK YOU! that was the issue. Code was not recognizing it as the name of the sheet until I added Sheets("") around it. I have other issues with my program which are unrelated, so I will mark this topic closed.

Comment: your're welcome. As suggested- try to declare variables which always help to solve some problems...

Comment: will do. I also never fully understood "option explicit" until now, so this was great clarification and a lesson going forward.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing quotes around your strings, and the `Exit For` was in the wrong place:

```
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If ws.Name = "Sheet1" Then
        Sheet1.Name = "Results"
    ElseIf ws.Name = "Sheet2" Then
        Sheet2.Name = "DataEntries"
        Exit For
    End If
Next ws
```

Putting the `Exit For` in the proper location will stop the loop after "Sheet2" has been found and renamed.

Comment: Upon making these corrections, I now receive an error "Invalid qualifier" on my next line, which is:

DataEntries.Cells.Clear

I will update the master code to add this, now that it has become part of the issue.